# eclipse market place connection issue

Tags: eclipse, marketplace

I have issue in connecting to eclipse market place from Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

I am getting below error when try to open eclipse market place.

"Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unable to connect to repository http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Unable to connect to repository http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Connection timed out: connect
Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Connection timed out: connect"

have tried changing window-->preferences-->General-->Network connections-->active provider to Direct/Manual, updating eclipse.ini with "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"..
None of the things worked out for me..

Please suggest me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is 12 releases and a couple of years behind. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The point in the comment is well-taken.  I find it hard to understand why so many people at my company are still trying to get Oxygen to work.

However, it is within the realm of possibilities that you can get the Marketplace connection working with this.  I would assume that you are running behind a corporate firewall.  There will be a particular proxy url you're supposed to use behind the firewall, which you have to configure in "Manual" mode in Network Connections.  If you don't know what that proxy url is, you won't be able to get this to work.

Once you get the proxy working, you may get a different error, related to SSL and certificates.  That would imply that your firewall requires a particular root certificate provided by your company.  Assuming that's the case, that certificate needs to be installed in the Java distribution that is being used to run Eclipse.  If you run into this, I would post a new question if you're unable to resolve this.